# Significato e origine dell'espressione "soffiare nel fuoco"

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-origin

Nel romanzo *Bàrnabo delle montagne* di Dino Buzzati ho letto questo paragrafo di un testo nel quale si parla dei lavori di costruzione di una strada di montagna:

> «Uno dei lavoranti va, una notte, a rubare in una casa. Danno allora la colpa a Bettoni perché non sorveglia abbastanza gli operai. Un suo concorrente che aveva perduto l'appalto ***soffia nel fuoco***. Minacciano di far saltare il deposito di esplosivi.»

Mi potreste spiegare cosa significa l'espressione "soffiare nel fuoco"? Sarei inoltre curiosa di sapere da dove nasce questo modo di dire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Di solito si dice *soffiare sul fuoco*, ma non è diverso.

Quando si accende un fuoco, occorre soffiarci sopra per aumentare la quantità di ossigeno a disposizione della fiamma e anche per eliminare il fumo che la potrebbe soffocare. Il soffio deve essere delicato per non spegnere la fiamma, naturalmente.

Quindi *soffiare sul fuoco* significa alimentare la fiamma e, in senso figurato, rendere la situazione più tesa, fomentare contrasti, risentimenti, passioni.

Vedi http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soffiare/